# Python Selenium if string contains exact match

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check a URL using python selenium to see what page the site is on.  I have the following urls...

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/page1
http://www.example.com/contact
```

I am using this python...

```
if "http://www.example.com" in url:
    print("The URL is homepage")
else:
    print("The URL is not homepage")
```

This isn't working because all of the URL contain the string, how can I change it so that it only works for an exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equality operator `==` as follows:

```
if url == "http://www.example.com":
    print("The URL is homepage")
else:
    print("The URL is not homepage")
```

It is convention to put the variable name on the LHS of the equality operator and the string you are testing it against on the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go a step further, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

```
import re

a = re.compile('.*example\.com$')
# .* ignores whatever comes before example.com
# \. escapes the dot
# $  indicates that this must be the end of the string

if a.match(url):  # <-- That's the URL you want to check
    print("The URL is homepage")
else:
    print("The URL is not homepage")
```